# PHP Not Reading Form Fields As Empty

Tags: php

everyone! I've been having a terrible time trying to figure out why my form validation doesn't recognize empty fields and return them as errors.

Here is a function I use to check the fields:

```
function check_required_fields($required_array) {
$field_errors = array();
foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) { 
        $field_errors[] = $fieldname; 
    }
}
return $field_errors;
}
```

Then, my form is process like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $errors = array();

    // perform validations on the form data
    $required_fields = array('client', 'banner', 'district', 'store', 'position', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password');
    $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));
```

and an IF statement checks for errors:

```
if ( empty($errors) ) { 
        $query =
```

The problem is, even if my fields are empty (and I checked them with var_dump($_POST)) PHP performs the $query. I think there is something wrong with the function. I hope someone can help me spot the error!

Here is the gist of my HTML code:

```
<form action="registration.php" method="post">

<label for="first_name" class="medium">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="textbox short_field">

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="form-submit-button">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

I also use the following functions to validate string length and it works just fine:

```
function check_max_field_lengths($field_length_array) {
$field_errors = array();
foreach($field_length_array as $fieldname => $maxlength ) {
    if (strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength) { $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
    }
}
return $field_errors;
}
```

and

```
$fields_with_lengths = array('first_name' => 30, 'last_name' => 30, 'email' => 50, 'password' => 30);
    $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));
```

Comment: And the HTML code? You have to include `method='POST'` in your form tag.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($errors)` to see what's in there?

Comment: Your `check_require_fields()` function accepts only one argument, but you are calling it with two.

Comment: I updated my question with more details. Michael, var_dump($errors) returns NULL. and the check_required_fields() does the same thing as check_max_field_lengths which also calls two arguments and seems to work fine. Not sure why one would work and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The problem is, even if my fields are empty (and I checked them with var_dump($_POST)) PHP performs the $query."

Your problem is caused by this condition: $var != 0. Php can cast variables of different types between each other, so empty string is equal to 0. Proof:

```
<?php
$var = '';
var_dump($var == 0);
```

Output: `bool(true)`

Now look at this sample, imitating, how php processes your condition:

```
<?php
$var = '';
var_dump(empty($var));
var_dump((empty($var) && $var != 0));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

In the 2-nd case the boolean function returns false, therefore, the variable won't be added to the array of errors.

I don't know, what do you want to achieve with this: `$var != 0`. But the condition:

```
if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || 
    (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) { 
      $field_errors[] = $fieldname; 
}
```

can be easily switched to this:

```
if (empty($_POST[$fieldname])) { 
     $field_errors[] = $fieldname; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, user4035! That fixed it! And, thanks to everyone else for their input as well.